# Haskell - sum of cubes of a list

Tags: haskell

I have to write a function that sums the cubes of a list of numbers.

This is my code so far:

```
cube' :: (Num a) => a -> a 
cube' x = x*x*x


mySum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a 
mySum [] = []
mySum xs = foldr (\acc x -> acc + cube'(x)) 0 xs
```

The problem is that when I run it I get the following error:

> No instance for (Num[t0]) arising from a use of 'it'
>
> In a stmt of an interactive GHCI command: print it

Comment: You're returning a list in the first clause, did you mean to return `0`?  Also, `foldr` will handle an empty list for you so that pattern match isn't useful.  you could just do `mySum xs = foldr ...` without caring what `xs` is.  In this case you can even drop the argument entirely and have the entire definition as `mySum = foldr (\acc x -> acc + cube' x) 0`

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely on the right track.  As bhelkir points out in a comment, the first clause of the definition is wrong and unnecessary.  The other problem is that you have the argument order wrong for the lambda.